# Dynamically replace .h and .m file in ios project(bundle path)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, iphone

I have using `calculation.h` and `calculation.m` files for some calculation in my project. Those calculations will come some changes while application in store. So I can only change those calculation and update to next version.

So do we have any logic or concept to change calculation at run time or we can replace or add `calculation.h` and `calculation.m` files in bundle path at runtime.

I tried API for calculation changes. So please suggest me any other methods.

Do we can allocate and initialize files which have in "NSDocument Directory"?.(instead of access in bundle path)

Do we have jsscript concept for calculations changes or any other method?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: use different methods for calculation

Comment: hi vijeesh, please explain in details. do you asking method name?

Comment: what actually you need to get

Comment: Vijeesh, I need to replace "Calculation.h" and Calculation.m" file in bundle resource at runtime.

Comment: why you want to do that?

Comment: Because my requirement is changing calculation at any time. So i can only update those calculation changes in next release.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76361/discussion-between-vijeesh-and-prabakaran-ios).

Comment: So only i replace those files in run time.  can you get my point vijeesh

Comment: @prabakaraniOS what you want to do is change the calculation logic / formula dynamically... this does not necessarily require replacing files in the bundle at run time (which is not possible..)...

Comment: i have over 1000 line code for formula and logic. So only i need to replace those file. vijeesh.....

Comment: lukya, we can access .h and .m file from nsdocument directory. Instead of access in nsbundle path

Comment: store the calculation methods in something like coredata instead maybe? then you can push updates to your app without having to do a full reinstall of the app

Comment: do you mean store "nsobject" class object to core data and access that?

Comment: I understand your question, but I don't understand the relation with javascript. Can you explain to me ?

Comment: @prabakaraniOS i was thinking more along the lines of formula strings that your program can interpret

Comment: we will implement calculation in java script and get the values from java script. is it possible.

Comment: Just to be clear [Apple's review guideline 2.7](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality) `Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected` ... so be careful.... if you are planning to submit an app with certain functionality and later somehow perform something else..

Comment: lukya, ok i'll search regarding this in apple guidline 2.7

Comment: lukya, Do we have any other way to pass calculation values?

Comment: You can store the values on the server, or in user defaults or a simple plist file even in a database... and use them at run time ..

Comment: However, theres will always be a finite set of rules or calculations you will account for within your app and whenever you come up with a scenario / condition / rule / formula / value which you haven't already handled (which is what, i assume, you mean when you say 'dynamic') .. you will have to make changes to the app code... and consequentially release an app update...

Comment: yes lukya. i'll change calculation .m and .h file consequentially update each time . So there is have any sort cut logic have to change calculation but not need next release in app store. We need change calculation while application in store.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DJJavaInsertion](https://github.com/ddaddy/DJJavaInsertion). It lets you run your class methods from a JavaScript string.

If you create your own `DJJavaFunction` subclasses to take your parameters that might change and pass them to your current code, then implement a way to remotely update the JavaScript string that is passed in, then you can effectively change how your app runs.